# Java чтение сертификата из памяти

Tags: java, x509certificate, multipartfile

Принимаю файл сертификата и хотелось бы не записывая его на диск взять из него поля, т. е. прочитать его из памяти. Принимаю файл:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws CertificateException {
```

Читаю сертификат так:

```
CertificateFactory fac = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) fac.generateCertificate((InputStream) file);
System.out.println("SN: " + cert.getSerialNumber().toString(16));
```

При получении файла получаю:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile cannot be cast to class java.io.InputStream (org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.io.InputStream is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')] with root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile cannot be cast to class java.io.InputStream (org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.io.InputStream is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй извлечь входящий поток из MultipartFile, а не кастовать в InputStream вот так:

```
CertificateFactory fac = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) fac.generateCertificate(file.getInputStream());
System.out.println("SN: " + cert.getSerialNumber().toString(16));
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!